# How can I find a locked MAC address?

Tags: scripting, mac-address, locked

I have 40 computers in my lab and I have locked each computer with MAC address so people won't be able to unplug the network cable and connect it to their laptops.
I was wondering, if a laptop is connected via one of those cables, can he do some actions and discover the locked MAC.
I know I can find the locked MAC by running ipconfig /all on the computer in the lab. but if it's locked by a password I can't.
I am searching for the commands that I can run on the laptop (while pluged via the network cable) that will give me the MAC address of the computer's lab (The locked address).

(BTW, I'm running windows 7)

Thank you very much!
Amihay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the laptop is running Linux:

```
sudo tshark -n arp
```

should net a few valid MAC addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll help because its windows,
From a windows Shell

> net view
>
> nbtstat -a COMPUTER-NAME